# How to add images from realtime database in every question?

Tags: java, android, firebase, image, firebase-realtime-database

Question Model-

```
public class QuestionModel {

    private String Id;
    private String question;
    private String A;
    private String B;
    private String C;
    private String D;
    private String answer;
    private String link;
    private String set;

    public QuestionModel(String id, String question, String a, String b, String c, String d, String answer, String set, String link) {
        Id = id;
        this.question = question;
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.set = set;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return A;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        A = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return B;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        B = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return C;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        C = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return D;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        D = d;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public void setSet(String set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

}
```

Question Activity -

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        broadcastReceiver = new ConnectionReceiver();    
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        noindicator = findViewById(R.id.no_indicator);
        bookmark1btn = findViewById(R.id.bookmark_btn1);
        optioncontainer = findViewById(R.id.options_containers);
        sharebtn = findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
        nextbtn = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
image =findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=preferences.edit();
        gson =new Gson();
        setId = getIntent().getStringExtra("setId");

        loadingDialog = new Dialog(this);
        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.round_corner));
        loadingDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);

        list = new ArrayList<>();getBookmarks();

    bookmark1btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (modelmatch()){
                bookmarksList.remove(matchedQuestionPosition);
                bookmark1btn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark_border));
            }else {
                bookmarksList.add(list.get(position));
                bookmark1btn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark));
            }
        }
    });

    setId = getIntent().getStringExtra("setId");

    loadingDialog = new Dialog(this);
    loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.round_corner));
    loadingDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    loadingDialog.show();
    myRef.child("SETS").child(setId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                   String id = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                String question = dataSnapshot1.child("question").getValue().toString();
                String a = dataSnapshot1.child("optionA").getValue().toString();
                String b = dataSnapshot1.child("optionB").getValue().toString();
                String c = dataSnapshot1.child("optionC").getValue().toString();
                String d = dataSnapshot1.child("optionD").getValue().toString();
                String correctANS = dataSnapshot1.child("correctAns").getValue().toString();
                String link = dataSnapshot1.child("imageurl").getValue().toString();
                                      if(!link.equals("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bcs-bangla-c2aa0.appspot.com/o/line1.png?alt=media&token=4ff22c6f-edd9-4571-844e-70612d066296"))
```

{
Picasso.get().load(link).into(image);

}
else
{
Picasso.get().load(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bcs-bangla-c2aa0.appspot.com/o/line1.png?alt=media&token=4ff22c6f-edd9-4571-844e-70612d066296).into(image);

}

```
                list.add(new QuestionModel(id,question,a,b,c,d,correctANS,setId,link));
            
                }
                               if (list.size() > 0){

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                    optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            checkAnswer((Button)v);
                        }
                    });
                }

                playAmin(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());

                nextbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        nextbtn.setEnabled(false);
                        nextbtn.setAlpha(0.7f);
                        enableoption(true);
                        position++;
                        if (position == list.size()){
                            ////score activity
                            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                                interstitialAd.show();
                                return;
                            }

                            Intent scoreIntent =new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
                            scoreIntent.putExtra("score",score);
                            scoreIntent.putExtra("total",list.size());
                            startActivity(scoreIntent);
                            finish();
                            return;
                        }
                        count = 0;
                        playAmin(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());
                    }
                });

                sharebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String body = list.get(position).getQuestion() + "\n  (A) " +
                                list.get(position).getA() + "\n  (B) " +
                                list.get(position).getB() + "\n  (C) " +
                                list.get(position).getC() + "\n  (D) " +
                                list.get(position).getD();

                        Intent shareaintent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareaintent.setType("text/plain");
                        shareaintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "QUIZ CHALLANGE");
                        shareaintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareaintent,"share via"));


                    }
                });

            }else {
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this,"no question",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });


}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    storebookmarks();
}

private void playAmin (final View view, final int Value, final String data){

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFCFFFD1")));
    }

    view.animate().alpha(Value).scaleX(Value).scaleY(Value).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(100)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            if (Value == 0 && count < 4){
                String option = "";
                if (count == 0){
                    option = list.get(position).getA();
                }else if (count == 1){
                    option = list.get(position).getB();
                }else if (count == 2){
                    option = list.get(position).getC();
                }else if (count == 3){
                    option = list.get(position).getD();
                }
                playAmin(optioncontainer.getChildAt(count),0,option);
                count++;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            ////Data change

            if (Value == 0){
                try {
                    ((TextView) view).setText(data);
                    noindicator.setText(position+1+"/"+list.size());

                    if (modelmatch()){
                        bookmark1btn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark));
                    }else {
                        bookmark1btn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark_border));
                    }

                }catch (ClassCastException ex){
                    ((Button) view).setText(data);
                }
                view.setTag(data);
                playAmin(view,1,data);
            }else {
                enableoption(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
}

private void checkAnswer(Button selectedOption){
    enableoption(false);
    nextbtn.setEnabled(true);
    nextbtn.setAlpha(1);

    if (selectedOption.getText().toString().equals(list.get(position).getAnswer())){
        ////correct ans

        score++;
        selectedOption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50")));
        //Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this,score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        ///incorrect ans
        selectedOption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
        Button correctOption = (Button) optioncontainer.findViewWithTag(list.get(position).getAnswer());
        correctOption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50")));
    }
}

private void enableoption(boolean enable){
    for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++){
        optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enable);
        if (enable){
            optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFCFFFD1")));

        }
    }
}

private void getBookmarks(){
    String json= preferences.getString(KEY_NAME,"");

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<QuestionModel>>(){}.getType();

    bookmarksList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (bookmarksList == null){
        bookmarksList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

private boolean modelmatch(){
    boolean matched = false;
    int i = 0;
    for (QuestionModel model : bookmarksList){

        if (model.getQuestion().equals(list.get(position).getQuestion())
                && model.getAnswer().equals(list.get(position).getAnswer())
                && model.getSet().equals(list.get(position).getSet())){
            matched = true;
            matchedQuestionPosition = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return matched;
}

private void storebookmarks(){
    String json = gson.toJson(bookmarksList);
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME,json);
    editor.commit();
}







protected void registoreNetworkBroadcast(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

}
protected void unregistorNetwork(){
    try{
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregistorNetwork();
}










private void loadAds(){
    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitialAd_id));
    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    interstitialAd
            .setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Load the next interstitial.
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

                    Intent scoreIntent =new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
                    scoreIntent.putExtra("score",score);
                    scoreIntent.putExtra("total",list.size());
                    startActivity(scoreIntent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }

            });
}
```

}

There are Question Activity of a quiz app. Here I want to show different image from firebase in every question for the quiz app. I have tried to show image.I have added imageurl in QuestionModel and tried to show using picasso library.But it did not worked.In every question same image shown although i have added different links of image(which i have stored in firebase storage and added the link in question in firebase) in firebase but with every question is shows the same image  . Please help  me to do this.

Comment: I don't see you putting imageurl or anything related data in arraylist while providing arraylist to adapter.

Comment: I have changed it...please now see this

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: It would be great towfique if you post without filtering the loops and condition.

Comment: You can print "link" variable and check you are getting different URLs.

Comment: i tried ..but it didn't work..every time it shows the same image

Comment: Did you check the link URLs..are they same or different.

Comment: I have changed the code ...you can see now i have used it...but it didn't work.